# Expected conditional covariance identity

Tags: probability, statistics, conditional-probability, covariance

I am trying to understand the identity in 2.6 of the following [article](https://arxiv.org/abs/2007.01283), in which we have random variables $X \in \mathbb{R}, Y\in \mathbb{R}$ and $Z \in \mathbb{R}^{p-1}$. They define the conditional mean function
$$
\mu^* := \mu^*(X,Z) = \mathbb{E}[Y|X,Z]
$$
and some estimate of $\mu^*$, denoted $\mu := \mu(X,Z)$. They then claim that
\begin{align*}
            \mathbb{E} [\text{Cov}(\mu^*, \mu|Z)] = \mathbb{E}[Y(\mu - \mathbb{E}[\mu|Z])]
        \end{align*}
which I would like to prove. Using the law of iterated covariances, we have for random variables $A,B,C$
\begin{align*}
      \text{Cov}(A,B) = \mathbb{E}(\text{Cov}(A,B|C)) - \text{Cov}(\mathbb{E}(A|C), \mathbb{E}(B|C)),
            \end{align*}
and so we can rewrite
\begin{align*}
\mathbb{E} [\text{Cov}(\mu^*, \mu|Z)] 
&= \text{Cov}(\mu, \mu^*) + \text{Cov}((\mathbb{E}(\mu^*|Z), \mathbb{E}(\mu|Z)))
\end{align*}

Then, considering the terms separately. We have
\begin{align*}
\text{Cov}(\mu, \mu^*) 
&= \mathbb{E} ( \mathbb{E}[Y|X,Z] \mu) - \mathbb{E}[\mathbb{E}[Y|X,Z]] \mathbb{E}[\mu]\\
&=\mathbb{E}[Y \mu] - \mathbb{E}[Y]\mathbb{E}[\mu]
\end{align*}
For the second term, we have
\begin{align*}
\text{Cov}((\mathbb{E}(\mu^*|Z), \mathbb{E}(\mu|Z)))
&=\mathbb{E}( \mathbb{E}[\mu^*|Z] \mathbb{E}[\mu|Z]) - 
\mathbb{E}[\mathbb{E}[\mu^*|Z]]\mathbb{E}[\mathbb{E}[\mu|Z]]\\
&=\mathbb{E}( \mathbb{E}[Y|Z] \mathbb{E}[\mu|Z]) - 
\mathbb{E}[\mathbb{E}[Y|Z]]\mathbb{E}[\mathbb{E}[\mu|Z]]\\
&=\mathbb{E}( Y \mathbb{E}[\mu|Z]) - 
Y\mathbb{E}[\mathbb{E}[\mu|Z]]\\
&=\mathbb{E}( Y \mathbb{E}[\mu|Z]) - 
Y\mathbb{E}[\mu]\\
\end{align*}

So putting these together yields
\begin{align*}
\mathbb{E}[Y \mu] - \mathbb{E}[Y]\mathbb{E}[\mu] +\
\mathbb{E}( Y \mathbb{E}[\mu|Z]) - 
Y\mathbb{E}[\mu]
\end{align*}
which doesn't give the right answer. Can someone point out where I've gone wrong, or suggest an easier proof?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your error occurs in simplification of the expression
$$\mathbb{E}( \mathbb{E}[Y|Z] \mathbb{E}[\mu|Z]) - 
\mathbb{E}[\mathbb{E}[Y|Z]]\mathbb{E}[\mathbb{E}[\mu|Z]].$$
The first factor in the rightmost term simplifies to $\mathbb{E}[Y]$, not $Y$. Fixing this should yield the claimed result.

A quicker proof applies the definition of covariance, but conditioned on $Z$:
$$
\operatorname{Cov}(\mu,\mu^*\mid Z)=\mathbb{E}(\mu^*\mu\mid Z) - \mathbb{E}(\mu^*\mid Z)\mathbb{E}(\mu\mid Z).$$
Taking expectation of both sides yields
$$\mathbb{E}[\operatorname{Cov}(\mu,\mu^*\mid Z)]=\mathbb{E}[Y\mu]-\mathbb{E}[Y\mathbb{E}[\mu\mid Z)],$$
using the same arguments as you've made, but avoiding having to add and subtract $\mathbb{E}[Y]\mathbb{E}[\mu]$.